# Issues with building Unity project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am implementing an external SDK that requires some changes in build.gradle, AndroidManifest.xml and UnityPlayerActivity.java. After implementing this changes direct build from Unity editor into APK file fails. The SDK documentation stands that I should export the project and build it from Android Studio, which I tried to do using instructions from [this article](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005695763-Exporting-a-project-to-Gradle-and-building-deploying-on-Android-Studio), but as a result I only got following massage in Android Studio console:

15:25:45: Executing task 'build'...

Executing tasks: [build]

15:25:45: Task execution finished 'build'.

and the APK file is nowhere to be found. I also tried clicking Build > Build APK(s) in Android Studio, but nothing happens.
I tried it also on new blank Unity Project with same result, so this is probably not the external SDK cousing the problem.

How do I build a Unity project in Android Studio?

Comment: Did you check for APK inside app -> build -> outputs -> apk -> debug **after** Build APK(s) command is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was importing wrong directory to Android Studio.

What I was doing (wrong):

1. Export the Unity project into MyDirectory
2. Import MyDirectory into Android studio

What I should have been doing (right):

1. Export the Unity project into MyDirectory
2. Import MyProject, which is inside MyDirectory into Android studio